Do they ever call him "Herbert the pervert" in the show?
I've never heard anyone on the show refer to John Herbert as Herbert the pervert. Did we all just agree to call him Herbert the pervert without the show telling us to?

I know he was called a pervert at least once at 2:20 in this clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y41vObbUf9k Not an answer because this is all I know about the show as someone who doesn't watch. Don't even know what episode.

To be clear: as in "Herbert the Pervert", that specific sequence of words?

Yes, those exact sequence of words

In short, no. There's a pretty decent set of transcripts on ForeverDreaming covering seasons 1 through 22, plus most of the various specials.
A very quick url search reveals no responses for "Herbert the" or "the pervert".

As @MeatTrademark has pointed out in an comment, he's referred to by another character as a pervert on at least one occasion, in the Season 6 episode Movin' Out (Brian's Song)

Stewie: Piss off, you perverted old freak

